# How to attach html file so that gmail's "view" option works

Tags: css, google-apps-script, gmail, html-email

I have a script that sends an email with an html attachment.  When I select "view" in gmail I get text...however when I click on "download" instead of "view", then open it, it displays as it should.

I think it's gmail related because I observe the exact same behavior from IE, FireFox(win/linux), Chrome(win/linux)

I made a youtube video of here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkGyxcFQXS8

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, Gmail is deleteing all CSS styles in the `<head>` of the html document I attach to mails. And note, I have no JS in document at all, only pure HTML and CSS styles in the `<head>`. I start to think more and more that Gmail is just junk!

Answer (score 4):

Not all email clients support the `<style>` tag. Gmail is one of those; it only respects in-line styling.

If your code is producing the css & html, then you could change it to use in-line styles for the table.

If you want something more auto-magic, see [How do I use Google Apps Script to change a CSS page to one with inline styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004225/how-do-i-use-google-apps-script-to-change-a-css-page-to-one-with-inline-styles/20689529#20689529).

Answer (score 3):

One way around this would be to have your script simply host the HTML file somewhere, and email a link to that file.

I cannot find any documentation from Google or the GMail team, but I would be surprised if they allowed HTML attachments to be opened and viewed (this would be a security risk, since they would essentially allow their email servers to host user-generated web content).

Comment: What get's me is that gmail will open word doc's and pdf's in this exact same way or by wrapping them in html (which seems like a slop that's equally as slippery), but I see what your saying.