# How do I use Google Apps Script to change a CSS page to one with inline styles?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sites

Background...

I am trying to write a Google Apps Script to get the content of a Google Doc as HTML and use that HTML to create or update a web page in Google Sites.   I already know how to do this but the result is a web page that is stripped of almost all of its formatting.  After looking at the html from the Google Doc, I see that it is not using inline styles and I believe that Google Sites requires inline styling.

Anyone have a Google Apps Script that I can use to convert the CSS to inline styles before using it to create a Google Sites page?  Also, a library that I could use within the Google Apps Script environment that would give me the same functionality would be just as good. It just needs to be a library that I could add within the Google Apps Scripting environment (i.e., through the "resources" - "manage libraries" menu).  Thanks.

By the way...

I have tried getting the html from a Google Doc in two ways.  Both ways give me the same CSS non-inline-style that gets stripped out when I use it to create a Google Sites Page.

1) I have used Romain Vialard's DocsListExtened Google Script Library at the following link...

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice

2) I have used code suggested by a few people including hgabreu@gmail.com, and others at...

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=585

Note: the same problem affects html email messages sent to gmail users.

Comment: Does the HTML code you get from the Google Doc have object types (divs, spans, etc) and class names? If so, you could just make your own CSS file that is referenced in your Google Site which would automatically format the HTML to look similar to how the google doc does.

Comment: The link to Romain Vialard's DocsListExtened Google Script Library returns "Page not found" error. The second link returns "Access denied for" followed my email address.

Answer (score 4):

There are [numerous online tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=inline%20css%20online&oq=inline%20css%20online) that do this conversion, so you could leverage one of them from Google Apps Script. (If you only need to do this once in a while, why not just use one of those services?)

Here's an example script, that builds on the `getElementByVal()` function from [Does Google Apps Script have something like getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695034/does-google-apps-script-have-something-like-getelementbyid/16702114#16702114).

#### inline() function

```
/**
 * Convert html containing <style> tags to instead have inline css.
 *
 * This example uses an online service from MailChimp Labs, but
 * the same principle could be used to leverage several other
 * online providers.
 *
 * @param  {Text}  htmlWstyle  A block of HTML text including
 *                             <style>..</style> tags.
 *
 * @returns {Text}             Same HTML, converted to inline css.
 */
function inline(htmlWstyle) {
  // Generate a POST request to inline css web tool.
  var payload =
  {
    "html" : htmlWstyle,
    "strip" : "checked"
  };

  // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
  // an HTML form. (We do not need to specify contentType; it will
  // automatically default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  // or 'multipart/form-data')

  var options =
  {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };

  var url = "http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  // The html from this service is non-compliant, so we need
  // to massage it to satisfy the XmlService.
  var badlink = new RegExp('<link (.*?)[\/]*>',"igm");
  var badmeta = new RegExp('<meta (.*?)[\/]*>',"igm");
  var badinput = new RegExp('<input (.*?)[\/]*>',"igm");
  var xml = response.getContentText()
                    .replace(badlink,"<link $1></link>" )
                    .replace(badinput,"<input $1></input>" )
                    .replace(badmeta,"<meta $1></meta>" )
                    .replace(/<br>/g,"<br/>");

  // So far, so good! Next, extract converted text from page. <textarea name="text" ...>
  // Put the receieved xml response into XMLdocument format
  var doc = XmlService.parse(xml);

  var inlineHTML = getElementByVal( doc, 'textarea', 'name', 'text' );
  return (inlineHTML == null) ? null : inlineHTML.getValue();
}
```

#### Explanation

There may appear to be some black magic in there. A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858731/html-div-nesting-using-google-fetchurl/16860598#16860598) described how to use the old Xml Service to examine the structure of a web page to find the bits you wanted. It's still good reading (and voting up, hint, hint!), but that service is now gone, and the new [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) doesn't have equivalent exploratory support.

To start, we found [a web service](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css) that did the job we were interested in, and used the [UrlFetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/?hl=en) to simulate a person pasting code into the service. Ideally, we'd like one that returned just the result we wanted, in a format we could use without any further work. Alas, what we had was a complete web page, and that meant that we'd have to farm it for our result. Basic idea there: Use the XmlService to parse and explore the page, extracting just the bit we wanted.

In the Css Inline service that was selected, Chrome's ability to "Inspect Element" was used to determine the tag type (`<textarea>`) and a way to uniquely identify it (`name="text"`). Armed with that knowledge, we had everything we needed to use `getElementByVal()` to dig through the HTML returned from a POST request. (Alternatively, you could use String methods to find and extract the text you want.)

But when that was all put together, XmlService kept complaining about the format of the HTML in the result page - so JavaScript String & RegExp methods were used to balance the malformed tags before passing the page on.

#### Example

Here's a simple example illustrating use of the `inline()` function. Note that style information is absorbed from both the external css link AND the tagged styling.

```
function test_inline() {
  var myHtml =
    '<html>'
  +   '<head>'
  +     '<title>Example</title>'
  +     '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/static/css/example.css" ></link>'
  +   '</head>'
  +   '<body>'
  +     '<style type="text/css">'
  +        'h1{'
  +             'color:yellow'
  +        '}'
  +     '</style>'
  +     '<h1>An example title</h1>'
  +     '<p>Paragraph 1</p>'
  +     '<p class="p2">Paragraph 2</p>'
  +   '</body>'
  + '</html>';

  var inlined = inline(myHtml);
  debugger;  // pause in debugger, have a look at "inlined"
}
```

#### Result

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 style="color: yellow;">An example title</h1>
      <p style="margin: 0;padding: 0 0 10px 0;">Paragraph 1</p>
      <p class="p2" style="margin: 0;padding: 0 0 10px 0;">Paragraph 2</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```