# Google Appscript will not render CSS correctly?

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a mailing template that will pick data from my Google Sheet and mail to the email IDs given in a particular row.

Everything is working as it is supposed to, but the CSS is not loading correctly as it should be loading.
Attaching code:

```css
        <style>
    body {
            max-width: 700px;
            font-family: trebuchet;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        #content {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #about_aum {
            background-color: #ebeff5;
            border-left: 5px solid blue;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 15px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="title">
                    <p>Hello <?!= name ?>,
          How are you doing? Trust all is good at your end. I am doing fine thank you for asking.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="body">
                    <p><?!= para1 ?></p>
                    <div id="about_aum">
                        <p>This is ABC Ltd, we are the financial services provider for most Corporates and clients in the country.</p>
                    </div><br>
          <div>
                    <p>Looking forward to working with you. Thanks for your time.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <?!= sign ?>
            </footer>
        </section>
</body>
```

As you can see above, if I try to mail it - it is not accepting the max-width property and neither is it applying the font I've specified.

I am using the `createTemplateFromFile` to fetch the HTML into the MailApp mailing service.

Comment: I thought that this answer might be for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20572401

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike

This was very helpful. I'll refer to the solution given.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I flagged to your question as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20572401