# Change GMail text color in the middle of a line

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, inline-styles

I am trying to work with existing Google Script, and I'd like to change the color of some words within a sentence in an email the script generates.  In the following, I would like "behind pace" to be red.  I've tried font tags, but they don't work.  Suggestions?

```
  if (firstItem) {
    body = "This is an email to inform you of course progress.\n\n" + studentName + " is <font color="red"> behind pace </font> in the following subjects:\n";  
    firstItem = false;
  } else { 
    body += "\n";  
  }
```

Comment: Did you tray `<span>` tag? `<span style="color:#FF0000">word</span>` ?

Comment: show all relevant code and show what you tried and didnt work.

Comment: Edited version above.  I tried replacing the font tags with <span> tags and couldn't get it running.

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` tag is what you're looking for; there is no `<font>` tag in HTML ([anymore...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)). The tag accepts a `style` attribute which uses CSS to describe the look of the span's content. (Learn a bit more about CSS [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp).)

```js
  if (firstItem) {
    body = "This is an email to inform you of course progress.\n\n"
         + studentName
         + " is <span style='color:red;'>behind pace</span> in the following subjects:\n";  
    firstItem = false;
  } else { 
    body += "\n";  
  }
```

Notes:

- You must send this email using the `htmlBody` option.

  ```js
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', {htmlBody:body});
  ```
- Gmail is one of many email clients that only supports in-line styles. See [How do I use Google Apps Script to change a CSS page to one with inline styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004225/how-do-i-use-google-apps-script-to-change-a-css-page-to-one-with-inline-styles)
- Be careful with quotes when embedding strings within strings. In JavaScript, you need to pair up single (`'`) and double quotes (`"`), but you can nest one within the other, or escape internal quotes (`"string \"internal string\" end of string")`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I still can't make it work.  I tried the code Mogsdad suggested, and the email contained this text: "Ima Nutherstoodunt is <span style='color:red;'>behind pace</span> in the following subjects:" I am definitely a novice, and I'm editing someone else's script, which I can't entirely interpret.

Comment: Did you read the "notes" I added? It sounds to me like you're sending the email body as text only, when it needs to be an `htmlBody`.